# Full width layout for custom post type pages

Tags: widgets, page-template, sidebar

I'm trying to remove a widget area called 'Primary' from a certain page on a site. This is the function where I manage the sidebars:

```
//ADD CATEGORIES IN SIDEBAR OF SINGLE POST TYPE
add_action( 'genesis_sidebar', 'add_mysite_sidebar' );
function add_mysite_sidebar() {
    if( get_post_type() == 'post' ){        
        dynamic_sidebar( 'News Categories' );
    } else if( get_post_type() == 'events' ){       
        dynamic_sidebar( 'Event Categories' );
    } else if( get_post_type() == 'documentlibrary' ){      
        dynamic_sidebar( 'Document Categories' );
    } else if( get_post_type() == 'bp_members' ){
        include(members_sidebar.php);
        unregister_sidebar( 'sidebar' );
        dynamic_sidebar( 'Members Widget' );
    } else if( get_post_type() == 'bp_group' ){ 
        include(groups_sidebar.php);
        unregister_sidebar( 'sidebar' );    
        dynamic_sidebar( 'Groups Widget' );
    }
}
```

I need to remove the 'Primary' widget area on the groups and members pages, but I don't see how to do it, and on the front end the widgets in that widget area are not in any overall container otherwise I could just hide it.

Comment: Are "Groups" and "Members" just static pages? If so, have you tried using the [`is_page()` conditional](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page)?

Comment: there are static pages for the main groups and members pages.. but these ones are buddypress generated subpages.. I foudn that the post type was the only way to distinquish them.. and that's working, but I don't know what code to use to remove that widget area once i'm there (in the last 2 if conditions)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Genesis, why don't you just use the Layout that doesn't contain Primary Sidebar? The layout option should be available right below the editor (as a meta box).

If you still need code, use plain CSS to remove the sidebar area.

```
function remove_primary_sidebar() {
    //Only if Pages with the following IDs
    if (is_page(array('1', '2', '3'))) { ?>
        <style type="text/css">
            .sidebar-primary {display:none !important;}
        </style>
<?php   }   
}
add_action('wp_head', 'remove_primary_sidebar');
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is force a full-width layout conditionally.

This code works in Genesis child themes only.

```
add_filter( 'genesis_pre_get_option_site_layout', 'wpsites_full_width_layout' );
function wpsites_full_width_layout( $opt ) {
if ( is_singular(array('bp_group', 'bp_group') ) ) {
$opt = 'full-width-content'; 
return $opt;
    } 
}
```

Source: [wpsites.net](http://wpsites.net/web-design/change-layout-genesis/)